# ng-change directive doesn't work as expected

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-change

In `$scope.invoicename` are stored  data for invoices with id, name, and pdfmake for each invoice. When user select invoice name, it should display pdf document designed by selected pdfmake. This is my html for select

```
 <select class="form-control"  ng-change="zafakturu(dizajn.pdfmake)" ng-model="dizajn.pdfmake">
     <option value={{dizajn.pdfmake}} ng-repeat="dizajn in invoicename" selected="selected">{{dizajn.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

And here are function called on change and function makeInvoice which should display pdf document.

```
    var makeInvoice = function(doc){

        pdfMake.createPdf(doc).getDataUrl(function(dataURL) {
            $scope.fajll= dataURL;
        });
        console.log(doc);
    };

    $scope.zafakturu = function (pdf){
        $scope.docDefinition = eval("(" + pdf + ")");
        makeInvoice($scope.docDefinition);
    };
```

And here is html element which displays pdf.

```
 <object ng-show="fajll" data="{{fajll}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></object>
```

The problem is, when I select one value, pdf with that value shows after second selection. For example, if I have  options 1, 2, 3, and I select option 2, pdfmake for that option will display only after I select 1 or 3. If anyone could help?

Comment: you should use `ng-options` over `ng-repeat` when creating select option lists whenever possible.  You may want to consider switching to the `ng-options` syntax and then updating your question if it still doesn't operate as expected.

Comment: also, setting `value` equal to your model doesn't make sense.  You don't want the value of every dropdown to be equal to your model....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$scope.$apply` to make the AngularJS framework aware of changes to the scope variable.

```
    pdfMake.createPdf(doc).getDataUrl(function(dataURL) {
        $scope.fajll= dataURL;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
```

The function furnished as an argument to the `.getDataURl` method is being executed asynchronously outside of the AngularJS framework. The `data` attribute of the object element only gets updated after a digest cycle. `$scope.$apply` creates the necessary digest cycle.